# PowerShell Select Replace Carriage Returns AD StreetAddress Not Working

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to remove all carriage returns from AD streetaddress attribute from output of export-csv file using

```
select @{Name="StreetAddress"; Expression= {$_.StreetAddress -replace '`r `n', "|"}} | export-csv C:\file.csv -notype -append
```

but it is acting very inconsistently and doesn't do this action to all the records. Does anyone know of a better, more reliable way? Apparently, a vendor app can't load data if it has a carriage return in it? I'm going to try Out-File next. Thx

Comment: ``$_.StreetAddress -replace "`r?`n","|"``

Comment: `'\s*[\r\n]+\s*', '|'` ?

Comment: It works! But why is this better than all the other posts out there Mathias? Thx

Comment: Mathias was first. How do I mark as answer? Thx. Also, don't use Out-File in this case. Doesn't work...

Comment: @MarcGel I've posted an answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left hand side of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use single-quotes (`'`), the backticks (`` ` ``) won't be recognized as escape sequences, but as literal backticks, so first you need to change `` '`r`n' `` to `` "`r`n" ``.

The sequence `` `r`n `` only works for Windows-style line breaks ([`CR+LF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)). However, if any object has a `StreetAddress` value containing a unix-style line ending (just `LF`), the it wont match, which is why you'd want to mark the carriage return optional with the 1-or-fewer quantifier `?`:

```
$_.StreetAddress -replace "`r?`n","|"
```